# way for teachers to post homework assignments

Tags: cms, vps, wiki, education

What kind of product would work to provide a feature on a school website to allow teachers to post homework assignments and allow students / parents to quickly find the assignments by class and subject?  I'm thinking wiki or cms but they don't seem to hit the mark completely.  FYI I have VPS hosting so I can install whatever I want.

Comment: I think CMS is such a broad heading that what you require could be classed as a CMS. A CMS could be any system where you don't have to physically edit the underlying code of the website. Is the "posted homework assignment" a simple block of text, or does it require images and advanced formatting? Do you want students to interact/comment on the website itself? Is it all to be protected behind some kind of authentication?

Comment: Just text is fine.  Minimal formatting (i.e. paragraphs, bullet points) would be useful. The only authentication would be to make sure that only teachers can post / modify / delete assignments and anyone can read them.

Comment: I have never tried this, but I have read the news today: https://code.google.com/p/course-builder/ . It might be worth a shot!

Comment: are you also interested in 3rd party solutions or just self hosted?

Answer (score 4):

I have used [moodle](http://moodle.org/) for a while, it is an open-source CMS that should provide all that you need.

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to use Wordpress with Buddypress and a plugin like this [courseware](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-courseware/) one.